# Bound of derivative function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\phi$ a smooth function with compact support on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\phi=1$  on $B(0;1)$, $\phi=0$ on $\mathbb R^n\setminus B(0;2)$ and $0\leq \phi\leq 1$ on $B(0;2)\setminus B(0;1)$. Define $\phi_{m}=\phi\left(\dfrac{x}{m}\right)$ where $\alpha$ is a multi index.

> Then what is $||D^\alpha\phi_{m}||_{\infty}$ for all $|\alpha|\leq k$ where $k\in \mathbb N$ also what is $supp(D^\alpha\phi)$?

I am trying but I am stuck.

Comment: What did you tried and what exactly is the difficulty you are having?

Comment: Without knowing more about your $\phi$ where is no way to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

First try to do the exercise in dimension one. You will find that if $\alpha$ is a positive integer, then $D^\alpha f(x)=m^{-\alpha}   f^{(\alpha)}\left(x /m\right)$ (prove it by induction). The best you can do it to express everything in terms of the supremum norm/support of the derivatives of $f$, $m$ and $\alpha$.

Then in dimension $n$, you will find that 
$$
D^\alpha f(x)=m^{-\left\lvert    \alpha\right\rvert    } D^{\alpha}  f\left(\frac 1m x\right).
$$